# How to sum a single cell that is dynamic?

Tags: excel, rtd

Input is a Real time data (RTD) function. So it constantly changes. Additionally, at times the value remains same meaning it should NOT be included in the sum.

RTD inputs in a SINGLE Cell (A1) as time progresses: 100, 30, 40, 40, 40, 30,30,190 etc..
Output (B1): 100+30+40+30+190= 390

Tried this `=IF(CELL("address")="$V$97",V97+V98,V98)`
It works but how do I get rid of the repetitive values, as I want to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Write a user defined function (UDF) that stores the last accepted RTD value in a variable.  Compare that variable to the current RTD value.  If they are different then update the variable with the new RTD value and add it to your output.